# How to post to Intel support community with username instead of real name?

Tags: forums

I just posted to one of the [Intel support communities](https://communities.intel.com/community/tech).  The post displayed my real name instead of my username, so I deleted it.  As you can see in the [list of discussions for a community](https://communities.intel.com/community/tech/desktop), people can post with their usernames.  But I went into my profile and my preferences, and I see no way to tell it to post with my username instead of my real name.  How can I post with my username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I changed my first and last name in my profile and reposted my message onto one of the Intel support community forums.  Then I looked at the forum in a different browser (which wasn't logged in to the community), and it showed my username on the post instead of my first and last name.  So apparently while you are logged in, you will see your first and last name on your own posts, but you will see usernames for everyone else.  Everyone else will just see your username.  This is different from every other forum I've used.